# mongoose how to prevent user already with username to modify username

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an auth system where user can either `signup` with `username`/`password`, or `facebook signin` with `provider`/`providerId`

I want to prevent change of username, but if they use `facebook`, I allow them to set `username` once. Is it possible to implement it in `user` model?

Here is my current implementation.

```
//username check unique
UserSchema.pre('save', true, function(next, done) {
    var self = this //in case inside a callback



    //sns provider, OK not to have username
    if (self.provider && self.provider !== 'local' && !self.username) {
        done()
        return next()
    }
    //not modified
    if (! self.isModified('username')) {
        done()
        return next()
    }

    mongoose.model('User').findOne({username: self.username}, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            done(err)
        } else if (user) {
            //todo: put msg in validation.js
            self.invalidate('username', 'username must be unique')
            done(helper.getValidationError('username must be unique'))
        } else {
            done()
        }
    })

    return next()
})

//username check is valid username
UserSchema.pre('save', true, function(next, done) {
    var self = this

    if (self.provider && self.provider !== 'local' && !self.username) {
        done()
        return next()
    }
    //username is required for local strategy
    var msg = helper.validation.user.username(self.username)
    if (msg) {
        self.invalidate('username', msg)
        done(helper.getValidationError(msg))
    }
    else {
        done()
    }

    return next()
})
```

The helper validation is defined as:

```
exports.user = {
    username: function(input) {
        if (!input)
            return 'username is required' //Note: required only for Local Strategy
        var min = 3
        var max = 10
        if (input.length < min)
            return 'username min of length is ' + min
        if (input.length > max)
            return 'username max of length is ' + max
        return null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your username property to null in the pre save function. That should prevent User from updating it's username.

There is also the option to delete username from the request body :

```
delete req.body.username;
User.update(query, req.body , options, callback)
```

Comment: I also use `update` route to set username for facebook user.

Comment: of course I can check in my controller, but I prefer to put all validations in model

Comment: I updated my answer. I think that if you set the username property to null it won't update it.